# Flutter and Firestore: How to update multiple specific documents from collection group

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Okay, so I have multiple specific document ids that are all the same, but each one is used for different collections and purposes.  Using a collection group as these documents are nested in subcollections, I was able to locate these documents and print them.  How would I go about updating a specific field in all of these documents at the same time with some other data?  In my case these documents despite being in different collections have a field called, `plastics` and I want to update them with int data.

Here is the code I used to retrieve these documents and filter to only print the one's I specificly need:

```
                      final String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

                      

                      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore
                          .instance
                          .collectionGroup("Members")
                          .get();

                      for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
                        var a = querySnapshot.docs[i];
                        if (a.id == uid) {
                          print(a.id);
                        }
                      }
```

Also here is some code I've used before for updating a field in a single document, but not all of them like I need to in this case.

```
Future<bool> addPlastic(String amount) async {
  try {
    String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    var value = double.parse(amount);
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('some collection').doc(some document);

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);
      if (!snapshot.exists) {
        documentReference.set({'plastics': value});
        return true;
      }
      double newAmount = snapshot.data()['plastics'] + value;
      transaction.update(documentReference, {'plastics': newAmount});
      return true;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, either loop through all the collections and sub collections (tedious), or store a list document references  in one of the documents and change the data by looping through all of these document references ( better option). If you need some code or guidelines on how to do that, let me know.

**EDIT**

To use the document reference part, first, when creating the document, you have to do something like this

```
document(id).set({
"value1":"oko",
"plastic":"240",
//And the rest of your values
"otherSnapshots":[/*Your list of documentSnapshots with the same ID. Update it in this whenever you have new one by following the next snippet*/]
})
```

When you create a new document, navigate to this and add in the document Reference by

```
snapshot.reference.update({
        'otherSnapshots':FieldValue.arrayUnion([/*Document Reference*/])
      });
```

And next time, when you want to update all of them, use this field, loop through it and then you will get all the document references. I cannot create a code that you can directly copy paste into your code without seeing how u store data

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm still learning but a code example would be helpful for the second option